# Fetch once a day laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

consider the following situation.

I am using the following public end point to fetch data: https://public-crest.eveonline.com/market/prices/

The details under `type` are stored in the database, it is fetched once a day at 1 am via a laravel task.

Great, that parts done. Now lets say the user wants to learn more about:

"Medium Ancillary Shield Booster"

They would click a link which makes an api call to the `href` and fetches that data. I would do it such that: if the data exists in the database use that, else make the call and store it in the database.

that parts easy too.

The hard part is saying: Make the call if the database doesn't have these details OR its been one day since the task was run. Now the table that stores the information does have `created_at` and  `updated_at` time stamps so would I say:

> When  user clicks on link to view more details, check if A) the item
>   details are in the database, ok they are, now check B) if its been 24
>   hours since the last time the data was fetched, do this by comparing
>   the updated at to 24 hours ago.

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes why not?, any way you can run a scheduled job that will query the api every 24 hours so you can say that if item is in db, than its fresh

Answer (score 0):

Self-expiring data is usually stored in cache (eg. memcached). I think it would be way more rational for you to do something like this:

```
$content = Cache::remember('page' . $href, 1440, function() {
    return $this->fetchPage($href);
});
```

Where fetchPage() is an imaginary method that fetches page at $href. So if somebody requests the same URL within 24 hours – cached value will be used. No need to fill your database with values that expire so fast and take care of cleaning.